# Assign indexes based on values in dictionary pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, indexing, assign

I have a dataframe with commenters and comments, on which I perform topic modelling. Due to the model I had to transform all the comments into one big list of sentences. On which I performed clustering. Now, I'd like to assign each commenter a cluster.

I have two dataframes:
[image]
[image: one looks like this]

The first one is the original dataframe, the second one is the output after the clustering.
and I have a dictionary with as a key the index of the author and as a value the number of comments (longer than 3 words) this person has commented. Now I'd like to assign each commenter a cluster, but I'm not sure how since the indexes obviously don't match anymore. So my question is: how do I assign the indexes based on the values in my dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you could provide a more complete example with exact strings where you start from, where you end up and the output you would like to get. It appears that `sentence` and `text` are the same excluding brackets. If that is the case then you can use that as they key. In general, the function should either keep the order or allow you to pass some additional info so you can join it back. Check the documentation of the clustering function. If it does not do that, then it should at least give back to you the sentence that you input which could be used as the key, after converting text array into a string:

```
df1.merge(df2[[‘sentence’, ‘cluster_id’]],
          left_on=[‘text’], right_on=[‘sentence’], how=‘left’)
```

More complex case would be if an author had more than one sentence. In those cases different sentences could belong to different clusters. It is still joinable, but you will need to think how you want to treat such cases.